# Why is there only one differentiation but several integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives, soft-question

Differentiation and integration are inverse operations of each other.

However, there are Riemann, Lebesgue, Henstock–Kurzweil, etc… integrations, while there is only one differentiation  $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Quote from a book [A Garden of Integrals](https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-31):

> The derivative and the integral are the fundamental notions of calculus. Though there is essentially only one derivative, there is a variety of integrals, developed over the years for a variety of purposes, and this book describes them.

Comment: That's actually not true. There are the [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative), [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), and [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), just to name a few I'm aware of.

Comment: Hmm, I think there are Frechet and Gateau and partial and total and weak derivatives too...

Perhaps there is no absolute concept of derivative or integral, only a general concept that we have (historically) defined and developed in different ways to suit different purposes

Comment: Even the definition of differentiation in the question has different variants depending on how you define the limit. Depending on how it is defined, you might be able to have a derivative at the boundary of a closed interval on which your function is defined, or you might not.

Comment: There's also Caratheodory's definition of the derivative.

Comment: Hadamard derivative, Gateaux derivative, Frechet derivative; then there is derivatives if distributions.

Comment: There is also the [Pansu derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansu_derivative)

Comment: And Dini derivatives, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative